# IOS 5 Memory Warning show blank TableView under NavigationController (not on IOS 4.3)

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, ios5, uiactionsheet, memory-warning

i'm experiencing a strange issue on iOS5 Simulator (and Device) with a NavController and a Memory Warning. I have a TabbarControl with a NavController inside and then a TableViewControl. From the tableviewcontrol i  present a ViewControl and then i have a button that show me an ActionSheet. When the actionsheet is visible and i try to simulate a memory warnig in IOS5 something strage happend. The ViewControl just reload and show normally, but if i close the VIewControl and try to return on the TableviControl (inside a NavController) it just show a blank page (without navBar) and the 4 TabBar buttons , if i change to the second tabbar button and then return to the first button then the Table load normally.

This issue does not happen in IOS 4.3 (simulator or device).

i am pretty sure that depends in the way the actionsheet present is view, but i try all the methods to present its view.

here some images.

[image: table]
[image: action]
[image: blank]

Comment: i have done a simple xcode project that replicate this issue, i would appreciate if somebody can test this and maybe tell me if i am wrong?

Comment: here is the project [link](http://gahan.altervista.org/navigat.zip)

Comment: i think that this issue happen only with an AlertView and a Memory Warning together.

Comment: This is an iOS5 bug, it happens with UIAlertViews too.